# PayPal confirm and then return a string HTML (js..or anything else...)

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment, confirm, steam

So i'm looking to make a website that you can use a PayPal "Buy Now" button, it will check to see if you've actually paid and then return a string, in this case, a Steam Game Key. Obviously I don't want to give them out for free... So i need a way to only give out 1 per payment for that thing. Lets say I have 1 item for $2. Someone buys it and they get a key.... how do I confirm that they've paid and then give them only 1 key from a list of them.... then remove that to not give it to anyone else.

It seems complicated, but when I google it, all i find is useless information. Basically,i want to make something like Humble Bundle or Indie Gala or something along the lines of those... how do I go around confirming someone has paid and then give them a key, then remove it from a list of them that are on the website somewhere inaccessable from everyone else on the internet....

Please help.  I hope i was clear enough for everyone to understand me. My english isnt that good. sorry.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask here. Your question is as it is now off topic

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/use-cases/uc_social-online-game-subscrip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me give you an overview then i will talk in detail.

- User press "Buy Now" Button.
- User redirect to the payment page and he may pay and may cancel.
- if the user paid the amount you got notification from paypal informing you that the user paid an amount with value x.
- you do whatever you need after this confirmation.

---

**Note : you have to wait to paypal notification.**

---

now lets go deeper:
**What is this notification and how to handle it ?**

its name is IPN (Instant Payment Notification).
consist of two parts:
1- setting at your paypal account to which URL to send this notification ( or at the html form ). 
2- creating the file that will receive the notification with any programing language you want to use.


**what is this file that recieve the notification?**

this file ensure that the user paid the amount you want and give it whatever the details you need about the transaction ( like his email, his name ..etc ).
there is a sample code already exist at paypal that ensure the security of this part.

 and you will edit this code to add whatever you want when you confirm that every thing is ok.
so the file code will look like:
- get info about transaction
- validate this info
- do whatever you want

**how this validation is working?**

validation process handle all cases at the sample code, first it send all the transaction info again to paypal to ensure that paypal is the one who sent this info not any other one who know the directory of this file.
then it validate that you didn't recieve this transaction before.

then you add your own transaction  validation like validate the prices and currency to ensure that the user didn't change this values during the process.

**how to know which user paid this amount ?**

you have to set the user id or any thing like that at the paypal html form like item_id so you can detect which user paid when you get the notification.

for more details please check :

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/